# Having two 8GB ram and two 16gb ram, will it degrade noticeable performance?

Tags: memory, motherboard, dual-channel, single-channel

Here's my memory details, I actually have two 8GB ram sticks, and two 16GB ram stick, I know how different ram modules disable something called dual-channel which degrades performance. Can someone clarify these a bit. Do I have to increase my 8GB to 16gb to avoid performance degradation. (or) is it fine for now?

```
sudo lshw -c memory
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: e
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 48GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: F4-3600C18-16GTZR
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: F4-3600C18-8GTZRX
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: F4-3600C18-8GTZRX
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: F4-3600C18-16GTZR
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
```

Update:

My current setup details,I have changed it according to the selected answer.

```
 *-bank:0
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
      product: F4-3600C18-16GTZR
      vendor: Fujitsu
      physical id: 0
      serial: 00000000
      slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
      size: 16GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
 *-bank:1
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
      product: F4-3600C18-16GTZR
      vendor: Fujitsu
      physical id: 1
      serial: 00000000
      slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
      size: 16GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
 *-bank:2
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
      product: F4-3600C18-8GTZRX
      vendor: Fujitsu
      physical id: 2
      serial: 00000000
      slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
 *-bank:3
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
      product: F4-3600C18-8GTZRX
      vendor: Fujitsu
      physical id: 3
      serial: 00000000
      slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)


# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASRock
    Product Name: Z490 PG Velocita
    Asset Tag:                       
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis:                       
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

Update:

```
Handle 0x000E, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 64 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000E
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 16384 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 3600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 04CD
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 3600 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Not Specified
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 5, Hex 0xCD
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 16 GB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000E
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 16384 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 3600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 04CD
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 3600 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Not Specified
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 5, Hex 0xCD
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 16 GB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000E
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 3600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 04CD
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: F4-3600C18-8GTZRX   
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 3600 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Not Specified
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 5, Hex 0xCD
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 8 GB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000E
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 3600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 04CD
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 3600 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Not Specified
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 5, Hex 0xCD
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 8 GB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x00BFFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 48 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x000E
    Partition Width: 4

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x003FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 16 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x000F
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0013
    Partition Row Position: 1
    Interleave Position: 1
    Interleaved Data Depth: 2

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00600000000
    Ending Address: 0x009FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 16 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0010
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0013
    Partition Row Position: 1
    Interleave Position: 1
    Interleaved Data Depth: 2

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00400000000
    Ending Address: 0x005FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 8 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0011
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0013
    Partition Row Position: 1
    Interleave Position: 2
    Interleaved Data Depth: 2

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00A00000000
    Ending Address: 0x00BFFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 8 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0012
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0013
    Partition Row Position: 1
    Interleave Position: 2
    Interleaved Data Depth: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, it depends.

it depends on how the mainboard is managing it and what workload you have, some have the restriction to have 2 of the same kind in each channel but others must have 4 of the same ram and some more have to have a ram kit to get it worked on dual, triple, quad-channel working.

It looks to me that you mixed 8 and 16 GB which normally not recommend. Most Mainboard manufacturing brands will write a notice about the Multichannel usage of ram. I.e. use 8GB on the channel on A and 16 on channel B, but please do yourself a favor and read the manual as I don't see which mainboard was used to.

Update, due to the Requester, updated its information

Asus states for this Mainboard (z490 as above shown)

For dual channel configuration, you always need to install identical (the same brand,
speed, size, and chip-type) DDR4 DIMM pairs.

Reference
https://download.asrock.com/Manual/Z490%20PG%20Velocita.pdf

This doesn't mean it may not work on this board but may not be tested for this board.

As already told you can try to have one channel filled with 8GB and the other with 16GB.

Comment: Added my motherboard details.

Comment: Thanks,I updated my answer to be precise as possible

Comment: Nice find on the pdf, but it doesn't say it will support triple, quad or flex channel, so it's pairs & only pairs that it is concerned with.

Comment: @Tetsujin this is, what my answer is telling - nothing else ;)